# HttpSecurity Regex matcher not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm configuring HttpSecurity for a Spring Boot rest server, and I need to make the create user end point not require authentication.

The mapping for the controller method is `POST /users/{username}?action=create`

I produced the following regex which I tested with online tools to make sure it matched correctly:

`(\/users\/)([^\/]+)(\?action=create)`

My only rule for usernames was that they cannot contain /, and so I believe that regex fufills that.

However, despite adding the following to the httpsecurity config:

```
.authorizeRequests()
.regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"(\\/users\\/)([^\\/]+)(\\?action=create)")
.permitAll()
```

I am still unable to hit my endpoint and am unsure why.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Apparently my custom filters would be applied unless I configured the WebSecurity object to ignore it completely, like so:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
    .and().ignoring().regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "(\\/users\\/)([^\\/]+)(\\?action=create)");
}
```

But now spring is complaining about not being able to find an authentication object...

Comment: HttpMethod.POST = should that be HttpMethod.GET ?

Comment: @JoeT definitely POST, a json object providing other details is included in the request.

Comment: OK I was seeing this "The mapping for the controller method is GET"

Comment: @JoeT Oh my bad! Fixed

Comment: Since the regex is contained with a Java string does it not have to have escape backslashes? @JoeT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original solution was authorizing requests that had been authenticated, the following makes it so ALL requests (anonymous or not) are good to go!

Add this to your custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
    .and().ignoring().regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "(\\/users\\/)([^\\/]+)(\\?action=create)");
}
```

And just for clarity, this is the controller method it is applied to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}",params = {"action="+Action.CREATE}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public UserModel createUser(@PathVariable(value="username") String username, @RequestBody UserModel user) {

    user.setUsername(username);
    return userService.createUser(user);

}
```